# My code returns this error "error: unknown: Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression (31:1)". How can I fix it?

Tags: javascript

```
for (i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
  str.charAt(i) -= displace;
  if (str.charAt(i) < 97) {
    str.charAt(i) += 26;
  }
}
```

What can I do to make this right?

Comment: What's your goal?

Comment: It seems you cannot assign a value to `str.charAt()` method

Answer (score 0):

- The left-hand side of a `+=`, `-=`, etc, must be a reference (like a variable or a property of an object)
- Strings are immutable
- Strings have a `.length` *property*, but it's not a *method* - don't try to call `.length`
- `charAt` returns the character at the index, not the character *code* at the index. You want to change the character codes, so use `charCodeAt` instead

You could make an array of the string's character codes instead:

```
const charCodes = [...str].map(char => char.charCodeAt());
// You now have an array of character codes, eg `[97, 98, 99, ...]`
const newCharCodes = charCodes.map((code) => {
  code -= displace;
  if (code < 97) {
    code += 26;
  }
  return code;
});
const newStr = String.fromCharCode(...newCharCodes);
```

```js
const displace = 10;
const str = 'abcdexyz';


const charCodes = [...str].map(char => char.charCodeAt());
const newCharCodes = charCodes.map((code) => {
  code -= displace;
  if (code < 97) {
    code += 26;
  }
  return code;
});
const newStr = String.fromCharCode(...newCharCodes);
console.log(newStr);
```